# my page was working fine but suddenly this error happened while compiling my react code

Tags: node.js, express, webpack

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mTZv.png)

```
Compiled with problems:

ERROR in ./node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js 20:11-26

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in 'D:\BooksGalore app\frontend\node_modules\body-parser\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "zlib": require.resolve("browserify-zlib") }'
    - install 'browserify-zlib'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "zlib": false }



ERROR in ./node_modules/content-disposition/index.js 19:15-39

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'D:\BooksGalore app\frontend\node_modules\content-disposition'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/destroy/index.js 12:17-41

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\BooksGalore app\frontend\node_modules\destroy'


ERROR in ./node_modules/etag/index.js 20:12-31

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\BooksGalore app\frontend\node_modules\etag'


ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/application.js 42:14-37

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'D:\BooksGalore app\frontend\node_modules\express\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/request.js 18:11-30

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'D:\BooksGalore app\frontend\node_modules\express\lib'


ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js 29:11-26

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'D:\BooksGalore app\frontend\node_modules\express\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js 16:11-26

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'D:\BooksGalore app\frontend\node_modules\express\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js 18:9-22

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\BooksGalore app\frontend\node_modules\express\lib'


ERROR in ./node_modules/mime-types/index.js 15:14-37

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'D:\BooksGalore app\frontend\node_modules\mime-types'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/mime/mime.js 1:11-26

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'D:\BooksGalore app\frontend\node_modules\mime'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/mime/mime.js 3:9-22

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\BooksGalore app\frontend\node_modules\mime'


ERROR in ./node_modules/send/index.js 29:9-22

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\BooksGalore app\frontend\node_modules\send'


ERROR in ./node_modules/send/index.js 39:11-26

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'D:\BooksGalore app\frontend\node_modules\send'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/serve-static/index.js 20:14-37

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'D:\BooksGalore app\frontend\node_modules\serve-static'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: With Webpack5, Node 18, these packages has been removed as default install. You need to either install browser polyfill or if you don't need them set them as null in webpack fallback. 
https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-path#module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-http

Answer (score 4):

I experienced this issue for some time to a point I created a new branch from some past commit.

Later after much research and review on my code I realized I was importing Router class from '@express' instead of '@angular/router'.

The line of code in ts file import which led to **errors** above is shown below;

```
import { Router } from '@express';
```

The code below is the **solution**.

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
```

**NB:** Router class is service that provides navigation among views and URL manipulation capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this error when using React and trying to display my json response to the screen. Since I used 'response', it auto imported response from express (I believe), which caused the errors. All I had to do was delete that response import in my component and it went away.

Comment: Ideally your React app and express app are separated projects, therefore imports wouldn't collide

Comment: I think he was talking about React with json-server as the backend. @OneCricketeer. I had the same issue

Answer (score 0):

**zlib** package is missing in your node modules, try installing the package again **or** try removing node modules and install the packages using `npm install`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the imports of the response in your code

```
import { response } from "express";
```

Answer (score 0):

So turns out VS Code will randomly put a useless import like this in:

```
import { set } from "express/lib/application"
```

I actually have no idea why it does this. But removing the extra import fixes it. The error is quite intimidating and difficult to debug. Especially if it occurs randomly and you are just working with a standard react app.

I would suggest looking into recent files that you've modified for any extra imports that are unfamiliar. Remove those. Should fix it.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the below line from the code

```
import { response } from 'express';
```