# ReactJS frontend suddenly cannot resolve many of it's node modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, node-modules

I have been working on this application for several weeks on and off. I followed the same setup process as I have for all of my past projects, installed all modules using `npm insall` and initialised the package.json file. Everything was working perfectly until today when I tried running the app and got a long error indicating that app was failing to resolve the many of the files from its node modules folder. A similar message to the one below was generated for what appears to be many of my frontend node modules.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js 19:11-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\MyProjects\Personal projects\LessonGeekLogger\frontend\node_modules\body-parser\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "zlib": require.resolve("browserify-zlib") }'
        - install 'browserify-zlib'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "zlib": false }
```

The whole error consisted of several instances of the above message stacked on top of each other, each for a different frontend node module.

I checked for some of the files that the error indicated the app was not able to find but found them all in the exact directories described in the error. None of the mentioned files appear to have been deleted, modified, or moved making this even more puzzling. I also tried restarting VS Code, restarting my computer, and attempting to run the app from a new terminal, all to no avail. Beyond that I cannot think of anything I could have possibly done to cause something like this as on the outside none of the node modules appear to have been tampered with.

I am still fairly new to web development and the ReactJS framework so please excuse me if I've missed something obvious. I can provide any other relevant information if need be. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can think of two things to try: 1. Delete `node_modules` entirely, then do `npm install` to completely re-install. 2. If even **that** didn't work, here's a long-shot: Delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`, then do `npm install`. BUt don't do (2) unless (1) doesn't work.

Comment: In the worst case, make a list of the modules you need, start a fresh project, copy over your source code, and add the modules one-by-one.

Comment: If the above suggestions did not work, you could try deleting `node_modules`, restoring the `package-lock.json` file to how it was and then run `npm ci`

Comment: I have tried running ```npm install``` before and after deleting ```node_modules``` and ```package-lock.json``` but nothing has made a difference unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out what was causing the error. Somewhere in my code the import `import { response } from "express";` was automatically added. For some reason removing this seems to have fixed the error but I still do not know exactly why. Thank you to everyone who responded.

[Link to other answer that had the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74549748/20051031)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Try to execute `npm i` in the terminal at the root of the project. If it doesn't help, then try deleting the folder `node_modules` and running the command `npm i` again

Comment: Tried both suggestions but unfortunately the same error is still being produced

Comment: try to delete `package-lock.json` and run `npm i` again

Comment: tried that already according to the suggestions above unfortunately, also no luck